# hadoop namenode –format not working

Tags: ssh

I am trying to setup hadoop-1.2.1 on ubuntu 15.4 version. I have done all the required setup but when running the command:

```
hadoop namenode –format
```

I am getting following message:

```
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

16/02/15 08:47:06 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = ubuntu/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [–format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_95
************************************************************/
Usage: java NameNode [-format [-force ] [-nonInteractive]] | [-upgrade] | [-rollback] | [-finalize] | [-importCheckpoint] | [-recover [ -force ] ]
16/02/15 08:47:06 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ubuntu/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Please guide me what went wrong as I am not able to run this command successfully.

Comment: Which blog or link you followed to create single node hadoop cluster? what command you using to format NN?

Answer (score 1):

Namenode should be formatted very first time and in case it is corrupted. **Never ever format namenode when it is running.**

In my case it's working fine. So please follow this

```
root@ashu-700-430qe:/usr/local/hadoop/bin# ./hadoop namenode -format
root@ashu-700-430qe:/usr/local/hadoop/bin# ./hadoop namenode -format
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

16/02/15 10:17:33 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = ashu-700-430qe/127.0.0.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.6.3
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.3-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.3-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.3-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.3.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r cc865b490b9a6260e9611a5b8633cab885b3d247; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2015-12-18T01:19Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_72
************************************************************/
16/02/15 10:17:33 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/02/15 10:17:33 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
Formatting using clusterid: CID-44f10aa0-6658-4a35-9cfa-843a8277554c
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: No KeyProvider found.
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=true
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.namenode.startup.delay.block.deletion.sec is set to 000:00:00:00.000
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: The block deletion will start around 2016 Feb 15 10:17:34
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 889 MB = 17.8 MB
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = root (auth:SIMPLE)
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: 1.0% max memory 889 MB = 8.9 MB
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 889 MB = 2.2 MB
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB = 273.1 KB
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.NNConf: ACLs enabled? false
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.NNConf: XAttrs enabled? true
16/02/15 10:17:34 INFO namenode.NNConf: Maximum size of an xattr: 16384
**Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode ? (Y or N)**
```

It will prompt you for Y/N

> Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory
>   /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode ? (Y or N)

Providing Y it will go ahead and format the namenode

```
16/02/15 10:21:06 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-799383395-127.0.0.1-1455556866943
16/02/15 10:21:07 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode has been successfully formatted.
16/02/15 10:21:07 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
16/02/15 10:21:07 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
16/02/15 10:21:07 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ashu-700-430qe/127.0.0.1
************************************************************/
```

**So in your case it has definitely formatted the namenode as you can cross check the Hadoop framework standard logs matches that of mine.**

Answer (score 1):

I ran `apt-get dist-upgrade` command on top of `apt-get update` command. It updated a few more files. Then I ran `hadoop namenode –format` command, it successfully formatted name node.

Don't worry about this message:

```
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ashu-700-430qe/127.0.0.1
```

Run the following command to start hadoop services:

```
start-all.sh
```

It will show following message.

```
starting namenode, logging to /home/rshukla/Work/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-namenode-ubuntu.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/rshukla/Work/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-datanode-ubuntu.out
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/rshukla/Work/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-secondarynamenode-ubuntu.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /home/rshukla/Work/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-jobtracker-ubuntu.out
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /home/rshukla/Work/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-tasktracker-ubuntu.out
```

To check if all the services are started or not, run the following command:

```
jps
```

It will show the following message:

```
29391 DataNode

29583 JobTracker

28957 NameNode

29729 TaskTracker

29513 SecondaryNameNode
```